# Драйвер AMD/ATI RADEON HD 3200

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd, hp, radeon

Как установить проприетарный драйвер `AMD/ATI RADEON hd 3200` на `linux mint 17.3 (ubuntu, linux)`, `3.19 ядро`? Пробовал просто ставить `sudo apt-get install fglrx` синамон запускался в безопасном режиме, производительность карточки заметно снизилась, удалил `fglrx*` также, как и поставил.

Ноутбук `HP Compag 615`

**lsb_release -d --short**

```
Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
```

**uname -a**

```
Linux Compaq-615 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:37:25 UTC 2015 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

**cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" -m1 | cut -c14**

```
A
```

**lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2**

```
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS780M [Mobility Radeon HD 3200]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 308c
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8042 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

**X -version**

```
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
Release Date: 2014-04-13
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-75-generic i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux Compaq-615 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:37:25 UTC 2015 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic root=UUID=bf365314-5a25-4031-be45-d3a18eb636a9 ro quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 pci=acpi vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:46PM
xorg-server 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Comment: для старых карточек лучше ставить нативный драйвер.

Comment: Который медленнее чем тотже драйвер на винде?

Comment: Ну поставьте винду. Xp наверное ;)

Comment: Интересная нынче политика, не работает что-то на linux ставь windows))

Comment: Ну вы сами ссылаетесь, что на винде что то работает, действительно - работает там используй это, зачем мучиться? Еще варианты, скачать с сайта амд древний драйвер и надеятся, что он будет работать, посмотреть что поддерживает legacy драйвер итд. Но я помню, что нативный для 3400 работает лучше всего. Что вы там србрались быстрое запускать ? Для видео и десктопа это работает, для игрушек все равно карточка старая.

Comment: В том то и дело что для видио и десктопа свободные дрова тормознутые(странно работает тотже lxde), по этой причине я и решил перейти на проприетарное. Щяс перебираю версии, некоторые ставятся но ссылаются на Kernel module: failed to build fglrx-8.961

Comment: Баг забейте, или патч сделайте, вам особо не помочь,

Comment: Не особо хочется компить ядро с неким патчем, пока попробую некие вещи

Comment: Не, вы не поняли, я предлагаю вам самому написать патч, и добиться его принятия в ядро.

Comment: Это на сарказм похоже.

Comment: Ну как сказать, это самый правильный путь, юзай что есть, не нравится - заплати денег или сделай сам.  Но баг забить с подробным описанием странности в lxde не помешает, глядишь и починят.

Comment: заплатить денег нынче некому, мои дрова нынче устарели (с сайта hp) они создавались для ядра 2.6 и для x сервера версии 1.6, нынче версия 1.17, будет работать проприетарные дрова, официальные нет, свободные коекак робят, думаю ускорять икс сервер модулями

Comment: Итог всей работы, свободные драйвера ок хорошие, использую только kde(иза того что он поддерживает аппаратное ускорение openGL и интерфейс иза этого плавный и хороший, с vdpau толком не решил(ускорение такое, для флеша нужное) драйвера стоят, ускорение в vdpau неакти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение очень простое, ubuntu свободные дрова имеет акселерацию даже на такой не поддерживаемой карточке.

В основном надо установить пакет `mesa-vdpau-drivers`.
Дальше поставить `vainfo`, `vdpauinfo` и по нему смотреть работает ли акселерация на va, vdpau(не робит, ставим еще это, в любом случае ставим). Поставить `vdpau-va-driver` `vdpau-driver-all` `va-driver-all` `libvdpau1` `libvdpau-va-gl1`. Такой набор работает в основном на любой карточке.